# Android: Proximity alert updating latitude longitude

Tags: android, proximity

I have registered proximity alert in one activity and want to update the coordinates from another activity. How do I do that? I have already tried creating an `unregisterProximity` method in the 1st activity but it doesn't let me make it static.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

pass the coordinates from one activity to the other or use `locationManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent)` with the same proximityIntent for when it was created

post code and add more info cause your question is not that clear